# Why does my computer say "Soft Temporary Disable" at boot after disabling Secure Boot?

Tags: bios, uefi, bootloader, secure-boot, hp

I have a HP PC bought less than four years ago.

I had several annoying issues with Linux due to this "Secure Boot" junk, so I disabled it in the BIOS/UEFI settings. Then I was able to install Nvidia GPU drivers and VMware on Linux without blocking error messages. However, it also altered the look of how my computer starts.

Previously, with Secure Boot enabled, it showed a graphical HP logo and then high-resolution text after the bootloader, when Linux was booting up prior to the GUI loading.

After I had disabled Secure Boot, it now shows a lot of low-resolution text, with no graphical HP logo, reminding me of what PCs used to look like when you booted them in the 1990s. Once Linux has kicked in after the bootloader, its text looks far more low-res and ugly (but not quite like the "native" font displayed prior to the bootloader). I find this odd, although it isn't a practical problem.

The question I have is this briefly displayed message (prior to the bootloader):

> **Soft Temporary Disable. To enable ME, check Active Management (AMT) option in F10 Setup.**

Yes, literally, exactly like that. "Soft Temporary Disable". What does that mean? It's not English, and I can't guess what they refer to. "Soft"? Software? Temporary disabled? Huh? Don't they really mean "Secure Boot is turned off."? What is "temporarily" disabled exactly?

Even if their English isn't the best (which alone is worrying...), it just doesn't "add up".

And what do they mean by "enable ME"? The "Management Engine" is an unremovable *hardware* backdoor, isn't it? Are they suggesting that I have somehow disabled it by disabling Secure Boot? None of this makes any sense.

I get zero relevant results when searching online.

Comment: Intel Management Engine can be disabled.  It just often isn't disabled by default.  In my research, it appears that on Dell hardware, Intel ME requires Secure Boot to be enabled.  I was able to find hundreds of helpful resources when I searched for that notification message.

Comment: I should clarify that when I say IME can be disabled, I mean it can be made useable since it's not configured and/or no services respond. The chip itself will still exist. Booting into Legacy Mode effectively disables IME.

Comment: "Hundreds of helpful resources"? What? Literally FIVE total unrelated search results.

Comment: Yes; As I looked further into the results i discovered that, but certainly more than zero. At least one video that explained, but it wasn't in English, so I can't confirm

Answer (score 1):

This message relates to the
[Intel Management Engine (ME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine) :

> The Intel Management Engine (ME), also known as the Intel Manageability Engine, is an autonomous subsystem that has been incorporated in virtually all of Intel's processor chipsets since 2008. It is located in the Platform Controller Hub of modern Intel motherboards.

[Secure Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#Secure_Boot)
itself is, according to this Wikipedia article, one of the modules
of ME.

It is normally not possible for the end-user to disable the ME and
there is no officially supported method for doing this.
However, it seems that for your computer module and BIOS/UEFI
version, with your BIOS settings you have found a method of
doing so.

I would guess that the "Soft Temporary Disable" will last until
the next boot, when the BIOS/UEFI will disable it again
(unless you enable the right BIOS settings such as Secure Boot).

Comment: What do you mean by "I would guess that the "Soft Temporary Disable" will last until the next boot, when the BIOS/UEFI will disable it again (unless you enable the right BIOS settings such as Secure Boot)."? This has lasted numerous reboots.

Comment: I mean it's called "temporary" because the BIOS will start from an initial state in which ME is enabled, then find out that this is impossible and disable it. However, the initial boot state will always have it enabled. So this is temporary until reboot.

Comment: I don't follow at all. Sorry.

Comment: ME is always enabled. Disabling it is only temporary until the next boot. I don't know of another way of stating that.

Comment: As I've said, it says this every single boot. Not just once. What are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, this will repeat on every boot. This is why it's called "temporary" - valid only until shutdown.

Comment: Makes zero sense. And what does "Soft" refer to?

Comment: For "soft" : I can't guess what was in the mind of the programmer who wrote this message, but can only think that it means to underline that no permanent changes are done to the firmware/BIOS.

Comment: For "Zero sense", I can't understand the difficulty : The BIOS starts from a state where ME is enabled, finds out that this is impossible, so disables ME. And this repeats on every boot because ME is enabled in the BIOS, and the option to permanently disable ME is probably not user-accessible in the BIOS menus that are available to users.

Comment: Let me try another way: ME is a technology that is built into the CPU, so cannot be disabled the hard way inside the CPU. The BIOS finds out on boot, when it checks the available hardware, that ME exists but then finds also that it's unusable. It then gives the message that ME is disabled in a soft way (meaning unusable but still available to use when Secure Boot will be enabled). This will repeat on every boot until you enable Secure Boot, and then ME will become both enabled and usable.